# Error in Graphical Modeler when converting raster to vector

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I'm building a model where, among other things, I use `r.watershed`, from which I only keep the `"stream segments"` output.

In addition I would like to convert that raster to vector lines. When I do that manually, I normally use the `r.to.vect` algorithm and it works fine. But when I try adding that last algorithm to my model, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 400, in processAlgorithm getattr(self, fullName)(parameters,
>   context, feedback) File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 452, in processInputs paramName, parameters, context) File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 690, in loadRasterLayerFromParameter self.loadRasterLayer(name,
>   layer, external, band) File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 709, in loadRasterLayer os.path.normpath(layer.source()),
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'source'

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I am experiencing the same. thank you